# Adding A Custom Label For a Chart Annotation In Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, charts, plotly

I'm creating a number of charts that will have a variety of annotations added to them that represent the presence of a single condition.

What I would like to do is add a label in the chart legend to designate what these annotations represent.

Here's a condensed example that can be recreated:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=100)
random = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
  #'data': data1
'data': np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=100).tolist()
}, index=dates)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['data']))
arrow_dates = df[df.data > 0.8].index
arrow_values = df[df.data > 0.8]['data'].tolist()
annotation_arrows = [dict(x=arrow_date, y=arrow_val, showarrow=True, arrowwidth=2, 
        arrowhead=1, arrowcolor='blue', yshift=10, arrowside='end') for arrow_date, arrow_val in zip(arrow_dates, arrow_values)]
fig.update_layout(annotations=annotation_arrows)
fig.show()
```

This provides the following chart:

[image]

What I would like to do is have a legend for said chart that describes what the condition is.  Ideally it would be an icon of the arrow itself with its description, something like 'Data > 0.8', with a picture of the arrow in the chart legend.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set this up elegantly in the legend, I think the best approach would be to include a new trace with markers that indicate when a certain condition is met. The snippet below does this with:

```
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['condition1']*1.05, mode='markers',
                         marker = dict(symbol='triangle-down'), name = 'Condition 1'))
```

Take a look at [plotlys marker styles](https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/) to find one that possible suits your needs better than `'triangle-down'`. This might not be a perfect solution, but at least you'll get the info you'd like neatly in the legend:

[image]

#### Complete code with sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=100)
random = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'data': np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=100).tolist()
}, index=dates)

df['condition1'] = 99

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['data']))
arrow_dates = df[df.data > 0.95].index
arrow_values = df[df.data > 0.95]['data'].tolist()
# annotation_arrows = [dict(x=arrow_date, y=arrow_val, showarrow=True, arrowwidth=2, 
#         arrowhead=1, arrowcolor='blue', yshift=10, arrowside='end') for arrow_date, arrow_val in zip(arrow_dates, arrow_values)]
#fig.update_layout(annotations=annotation_arrows)

df['condition1'] = df['data'].where(df['data']>95)

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['condition1']*1.05, mode='markers',
                         marker = dict(symbol='triangle-down'), name = 'Condition 1'))

fig.show()
```